# Maven plugin: Modifying resources before packaging

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I couldn't find a maven plugin that met my needs for minimizing javascript and css, so I started to create my own. However, I seem to have hit a roadblock. The minimized versions of the files always get overwritten by either the war plugin or something else.

My file structure is

```
src
   main
       java
       webapp
           assets
                 css
                   style1.css
                   style2.css
                   style3.css
                 js
                   script1.js
                   script2.js
                   script3.js
```

My plugin takes those, minimizes them, and (is supposed to) replaces them in the build directory. How to I make sure that they are not overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does your plugin output the altered files to? The way I see it, it's making the necessary changes (if it works) and then the maven war plugin copies the original resources over them.

Perhaps you should attach your code and pom.xml, for a better answer.

EDIT:

After having had a look at your test project, the problem can been resolved with the following change to your pom.xml:

```
diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
index 0fb6044..ee693f7 100644
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
@@ -72,9 +72,17 @@
                                <version>2.2</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
+                                       <warSourceExcludes>assets</warSourceExcludes>
+
                                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
+                                       <webResources>
+                                               <resource>
+                                                       <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
+                                                       <directory>${project.build.directory}/minified</directory>
+                                               </resource>
+                                       </webResources>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
-</project>
\ No newline at end of file
+</project>
```

I am also under the impression that your modified css files are being altered into the `src/main/webapp/assets` directory which is incorrect. These files should only be changed after being copied over to the respective directory under the target directory.

I have forked your repository and sent you a pull request.

Comment: I will put it on github soon and then reply.

Right now, it outputs it to ${project.build.directory}/${finalName}/ and then the file structure from the webapp folder

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is getting overriden, I am just not sure how I should be doing this... this is the first time I have created a maven plugin...

Comment: If you put it on GitHub, I'll have a look.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... Here is the repo https://github.com/alta189/maven-minify-plugin

Comment: This is great, but... how about a simple test case which illustrates what fails and how to reproduce it? As far as I can tell, this plugin takes care of creating the war file itself...?

Comment: Let me throw a test together... No, that was an attempt to fix the issue. I modified the war plugin's config to add a webResource. It appears that resources are copied, then the webapp's source is copied over that therefore overwriting my minified files

Comment: https://github.com/alta189/webapp-test However, my adding to the configuration of the war plugin doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The repo was changed for the plugin to https://github.com/alta189/minifier-maven-plugin because only org.apache.maven.plugins or something can use maven-(something)-plugin

Comment: They aren't modified there... the war plugin keeps copying them 
    [INFO] Copying webapp webResources [.../test/target/minified] to [.../test/src/main/webapp]

Comment: partially.... But now it copies the modified files over the originals in src/main/webapp

Comment: Ha! You're right, the war plugin is indeed copying them to the resources directory. WTF?!

Comment: Well, this appears to be a bug in the war plugin. I have filed it here: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-283 .

Comment: Great! Might be that you still don't have reputation!
Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend just using http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html which is capable of compressing and merging JS/CSS for you.

Next to that you need to figure out which plugin actually overwrites your compressed files and in which phase that happens. Once you know the phase you need to make sure that you plugin runs *after* the other plugin.

Comment: The point is that I don't want it to merge, I already tried that plugin, it didn't meet my needs. Also, I know what overwrites them, its the war plugin. It copies resources, then src/main/webapp and finally it packages it. All in the same phase